# Programmatically search for a string inside of an Excel macro

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

I need to programmatically search SharePoint for a specific Excel macro. I did some testing, and this text does not appear to be indexed. I'm not certain how to script this.

Generally, is it possible to search for document content that hasn't been indexed, or would the file need to be accessed outside of SharePoint to accomplish this?

Comment: Excel macros, as you stated, are not indexed or searchable in SharePoint.  If it is not indexed you can't search for it.

Comment: I understand this to mean: SharePoint only supports indexed searches. Generally, it is not always true to say "if it is not indexed you can't search for it". For example, Windows supports indexed searches but it can also perform a slower, logical file search by iterating through the file system. Even if this was possible in SharePoint, it would make more sense on the back end, though. Thank you.